# qtcreator + gdb, expanding macro definition

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, qt-creator

I use QtCreator and gdb 7.7. I have an example macro:

```
#define getMax(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

Then somewhere in the code a breakpoint is set when that macro is used:

```
break at line: x = getMax(v, z);
```

Is it possible to see expanded macro during debugging ?

**Edit1** How to check value of the variable, for example func ## Index or curr after expanded following macro:

```
#define WRAPABLE_HND_FUNCTN(func, ...)                      \
{                                   \
     enum { num = func ## Index };                                       \
     unsigned int curr = mCurrFunction[num];                \
     while (mCurrFunction[num] < mInterface.size () &&          \
     !mInterface[mCurrFunction[num]].enabled[num])      \
            ++mCurrFunction[num];                       \
     if (mCurrFunction[num] < mInterface.size ())           \
     {                                  \
         mInterface[mCurrFunction[num]++].obj-> func (__VA_ARGS__); \
         mCurrFunction[num] = curr;                 \
         return;                                \
     }                                  \
     mCurrFunction[num] = curr;                     \
}
```

When I execute `print handleEventIndex` (which was func ## Index) I get:

```
554print handleEventIndex
&"print handleEventIndex\n"
~"$2 = CompScreen::handleEventIndex"
~"\n"
554^done
```

For `print curr` I get:

```
555print curr
&"print curr\n"

&"No symbol \"curr\" in current context.\n"
555^error,msg="No symbol \"curr\" in current context."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to compile your program with full macro support:

```
g++ -ggdb3
```

When debugging on Qt Creator, enable the Debugger Log view and type the following in the resulting console:

```
macro expand getMax(v, z)
```

More information on the [GDB Manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/).

Comment: No Idea about Edit1; Honestly I have never used gdb's macro expansion. If gdb doesn't allow you to step into the macro then it seems you are out of luck. The error `No symbol "curr" in current context` is apparently gdb's way to say "I'm not stepping into the braces at `WRAPABLE_HND_FUNCTN`".